# Add Nokogiri parse result to variable

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, web-testing

I have an XML document:

```
<cred>
<login>Tove</login>
<pass>Jani</pass>
</cred>
```

My code is:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'selwet'

context "parse xml" do doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test.xml"))
doc.xpath("cred/login").each do

|char_element|

puts char_element.text

end

should "check" do
Unit.go_to "http://www.ya.ru/"
Unit.click '.b-inline'
Unit.fill '[name="login"]', @login
end
```

When I run my test I get:

```
 Tove
 0
```

But I want to insert the parse result to `@login`. How can I get variables with the parsing result? Do I need to insert the `login` and `pass` values from the XML to fields in the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like this to get the values:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<cred>
<login>Tove</login>
<pass>Jani</pass>
</cred>
EOT

login = doc.at('login').text # => "Tove"
pass = doc.at('pass').text # => "Jani"
```

Nokogiri makes it really easy to access values using CSS, so use it for readability when possible. The same thing can be done using XPath:

```
login = doc.at('//login').text # => "Tove"
pass = doc.at('//pass').text # => "Jani"
```

but having to add `//` twice to accomplish the same thing is usually wasted effort.

The important part is [`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#at-instance_method), which returns the first occurrence of the target. [`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#at-instance_method) allows us to use either CSS or XPath, but CSS is usually less visually noisy.

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of *login* from your XML with

```
@login = doc.xpath('//cred/login').text
```